# Criando vários Snippets

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, atom

Boa tarde.
Procurei aqui (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Batom%5D+Snippets), mas não consegui ajuda, por isso resolvi abir esse post.

Atualmente uso o phpStorm, mas ele é muito pesado, por isso vou começar a testar o Atom.

Estou tendo dificuldades em recriar meus Snippets que estavam no phpStorm e recriar no `snippets.cson`. Sempre aparece **Duplicate key**.

Como é a forma correta de criar vários Snippets no Atom?

```
################################################
#        JS
################################################
'.source.js':
   'Console log':
     'prefix': 'log'
     'body': 'console.log $1'

'.source.js':
  '$("#").val()':
    'prefix': '$'
    'body': '$("#").val()'

################################################
#        PHP
################################################
'.source.php':
  'Select':
    'prefix': 'select'
    'body': """
        $rs = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE coluna = '".$_GET['id']."' ");
        $row_rs = $rs->fetch_assoc();
        $rowTotal = $rs->num_rows;
        echo $row_rs['nome'];
    """

################################################
#        HTML
################################################

'.source.html':
  'Controller text':
    'prefix': '?'
    'body': '<?= $resultado["###"]; ?>'

'.source.html':
  'Snippet Name':
    'prefix': 'Snippet Trigger'
    'body': """
    echo "<script>alert('Mensagem');</script>";
    """
```

**VERSÃO 2**

```
################################################
#        JS
################################################
'.source.js':
   'Console log':
     'prefix': 'log'
     'body': 'console.log $1'

  '$("#").val()':
    'prefix': '$'
    'body': '$("#").val()'

################################################
#        PHP
################################################
'.source.php':
  'Select':
    'prefix': 'select'
    'body': """
        $rs = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE coluna = '".$_GET['id']."' ");
        $row_rs = $rs->fetch_assoc();
        $rowTotal = $rs->num_rows;
        echo $row_rs['nome'];
    """

  'Alert':
    'prefix': 'alert'
    'body': """echo "<script>alert('Mensagem');</script>";"""

################################################
#        HTML
################################################

'.source.html':
  'echo':
    'prefix': '?'
    'body': '<?= $resultado["###"]; ?>'


    'html5':
      'prefix': 'html5'
      'body': """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="pt-br">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <title></title>

            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        </head>
        <body>




        </body>
        </html>
      """
```

Answer (score 0):

Como especificado na [documentação](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/#multiple-snippets-per-source), basta você definir o *source* apenas uma vez:

```
################################################
#        JS
################################################
'.source.js':
   'Console log':
     'prefix': 'log'
     'body': 'console.log $1'

  '$("#").val()':
    'prefix': '$'
    'body': '$("#").val()'

################################################
#        PHP
################################################
'.source.php':
  'Select':
    'prefix': 'select'
    'body': """
        $rs = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE coluna = '".$_GET['id']."' ");
        $row_rs = $rs->fetch_assoc();
        $rowTotal = $rs->num_rows;
        echo $row_rs['nome'];
    """

################################################
#        HTML
################################################

'.source.html':
  'Controller text':
    'prefix': '?'
    'body': '<?= $resultado["###"]; ?>'

  'Snippet Name':
    'prefix': 'Snippet Trigger'
    'body': """
    echo "<script>alert('Mensagem');</script>";
    """
```

Comment: Olá Anderson, obrigado pela ajuda. Os snipts de html não estão funcionando, vejam a imagem http://prntscr.com/nyi3sp

Comment: @Tiago e pela imagem fica claro o problema: indentação

Comment: Como assim? Como deve ficar?

Comment: Da mesma forma que eu coloquei na resposta

Comment: Eu copiei e colei no meu arquivo, só adicionei mais uma chamada html5.

Comment: Atualizei meu código colocando a VERSÃO 2, por gentileza, de uma olhada.

Comment: @Tiago Veja que o snippet `html5` está indentado em relação ao snippet anterior. Basta remover esse nível de indentação. Deveria estar indentado apenas com 2 espaços, está com 4. Na documentação citada há mais detalhes sobre a sintaxe utilizada se precisar.

Comment: Acho que to muito burro...rsrs, sinceramente, não estou conseguindo visualizar o que esta me passando. Pode estar muito claro para você, mas eu não consigo ver essa minha falha :(

Comment: Sabe o que é indentação?

Comment: snip (http://prntscr.com/nyiaay). Usando (http://prntscr.com/nyiajy) o html5 que eu criei não esta sendo reconhecido.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94599/discussion-between-anderson-carlos-woss-and-tiago).